# Is there an console based usermanagement-tool for debian?

Tags: debian, user-management, console

i'm using Debian Squeeze.

I just wondered if there is a simple console (maybe curses) based user-management-tool for Debian?

I'm not looking for something bloated like YAST, but for somthing simple like there is with `sysv-rc-conf` for runlevel editing.

I know there is WebMin, which can do this and much much more... But it doesn't feel good for me to expose the whole Linux-System to the internet.

Is there something like a console-based WebMin?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`adduser` runs fine in a console.

Comment: yeah, i know... i was looking for something more _comfortable_... maybe something that lists me all users on a system, lets me edit them in a comfortable way etc... without having to type `less/etc/passwd`, `addgrp` `passwd` and so on every time :) Like i mentioned with the example of runlevels: I _could_ manage runlevels by making symlinks under `/etc/init.d/...` as well. But its more comfortable with `sysv-rc-conf`. Get what i mean?

Comment: @crushervx If you're the admin for a Linux server, you might as well stop fighting against the well established, well documented, and widely used native tools.